# Clickable HTML hyperlink within Label Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, html, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I'm trying to make HTML hyperlinks within a xaml label clickable. I have created classes which take a string containing HTML from an API, and renderer it correctly as HTML inside of a custom label renderer in both Android and iOS. To understand my dilemma better, its necessary to explain the extent of my use.

Inside my app, I have a messaging component that simply uses an API to post and get conversations from a website which is used primarily for better helping our users since our office is closed due to the coronavirus. The messaging center on the site allows for complex text formatting like a web forums post may, such as bold, italics, hyperlinks, etc.

In order to display this correctly on mobile, I had to create a custom label renderer that will take the string with HTML tags and display it correctly as the body of the message. This was a simple enough task.

The issue becomes that the messages may sometimes have hyperlinks, which currently display correct as links, but when a user tries to click on a link the list item is what registers the tap, not the label, nor the html link within the label.

The expected result is that when a user clicks on the hyperlink within the label, within the list, it will open that hyperlink in the devices default browser.

I understand that one solution may be to parse the body of the message for any links, create a list of links, and then dynamically add spans to a label that each have their own gesture recognizers, but this won't be possible for me due to the hyperlinks being at times midway through a conversation. An example of a messages body may be:

'Hello **user**, please go to [this link](http://google.com) to login to your account.'

I understand there are better ways to create a messaging app than this, but the primary purpose of the mobile side is for users to get easier access to responses from staff, and for simple chat responses to staff messages. Staff will use the site exclusively to respond to users, and may utilize the complex editor to better assist users.

Thank you. 
EDIT:
[image: conversation example]

In the above example, the link at the end is not clickable. When i click on the link, the whole list view item highlights as if that ui element is higher priority than the label within.

Code associated:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame
                        Margin="5"
                        Padding="0"
                        BorderColor="LightGray"
                        CornerRadius="15"
                        HasShadow="False">
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout
                                Padding="5"
                                BackgroundColor="#f5f5f5"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label
                                    Margin="5,2.5,5,2.5"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Small"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    Text="{Binding SentBy}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Label
                                    Margin="5,2.5,5,2.5"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                                    FontSize="Small"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                                    Text="{Binding Sent}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label
                                    Margin="2.5"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    FontSize="Small"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                    Text="{Binding Body}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    TextType="Html"
                                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What is your question?  You posted eight paragraphs of explanation but I don't see a single question.  There is also NO code posted.  If you need help debugging code, you have to show us that code.

Comment: further, Label now natively supports HTML, you should not have to create a custom renderer

Comment: How to make hyperlinks within a label, within a list, clickable. I'll add pictures to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: "I understand that one solution  ..." - this sounds perfectly reasonable to me.  I'm not sure why you don't think this will work

Comment: It supports it natively? I had it set without a custom renderer where I was binding the text property of the label to a string containing HTML and had no luck, it displayed the tags without formatting. like this: '<p>This is a test</p>'.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html

Comment: Jason, I added more explanation and a picture of what I am talking about in the app. Does that help you understand my problem?

Comment: I still don't understand why you can't just make the link a span within your label with a gesture attached.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm just not sure I understand how I would find the links and then add a span into the correct place, with a gesture recognizer that takes you to the url.

Comment: finding links within a string is a well known problem that has many solutions.

Comment: I found a way to make the links clickable (as per the answer below's link), but everything else loses its formatting, and the tags on the link are still visible as well. Ideally I would have clickable links and keep formatting like bold, italics, underline, color changes too in each span.

Comment: A flaw with spans is their lack of ability to use the tag 'TextType="Html"', which at this point would solve everything.

Comment: I've exact requirement, @cjpartin were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Reposting/edit my previous answer as it got removed for incompleteness.

This should be of some help:

> Showing part of a label as a clickable link, has been a long desired
>   feature of Xamarin.Forms. With the release of 3.2.0, this is now
>   possible.

Tappable Span

Create a Label, with a FormattedText property and spans as shown below. For those not familar, labels, have a property called FormattedText. It allows you to split text into separate sections, so you can format each of them differently.

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Hello " />
            <Span Text="Click Me!"
                  TextColor="Blue"
                  TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="https://xamarin.com" />
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
            <Span Text=" Some more text." />
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

In your ViewModel, add the following Command.

```
public ICommand ClickCommand => new Command<string>((url) =>
{
    Device.OpenUri(new System.Uri(url));
});
```

This will result in a label, with Click Me! text highlighted. Tapping the text, will result in the browser opening and going to xamarin.com.

Reference: https://xamarinhelp.com/hyperlink-in-xamarin-forms-label/

Comment: This won't work as FormattedString has performance issues with CollectionView/ListViews

Comment: This will work for static data, the question is on dynamic data and populated in a collectionview/ listview